# How to make a sprite appear before text in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a small RPG like game in Pygame and I have a function that prints text slowly (like in a lot of RPGs) and a function that creates a sprite. When I call them they both work however the sprite doesn't appear until after the text is done printing.

I have tried moving the sprite function around but so far, depending on where I put it, it either doesn't change anything or the sprite just doesn't show up at all. I have also tried putting a sprite drawing function inside of the text function but that didn't work either.

I was wondering if there is a way to make it so the sprite appears before the text. Below is the functions for printing the text slow and for creating the sprite.

```
place_holder = pygame.image.load('place_holder_frog.png')

def char_sprite(surface,img,tuple):
  x,y = tuple
  surface.blit(img, (x,y))

def display_text_animation(surface, s_color, string, tuple):
    x,y = tuple
    text = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        surface.fill(s_color)
        text += string[i]
        text1 = font.render(text, True, WHITE, BLACK)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, WHITE, [text_x, text_y, 400, 50],1)
        textRect = text1.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (x, y)
        surface.blit(text1, textRect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(100)
```

Below is the code where I actually call those functions:

```
if screen_num == 0:
  display_text_animation(display_surface, BLACK, "hello world", (text_x + 65, text_y + 25))
  char_sprite(display_surface,place_holder, (text_x -100, text_y - 25))

while carryOn:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
      carryOn=False
    elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key==pygame.K_x: #Pressing the x Key will quit the game
        carryOn=False
  pygame.display.flip()
  clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to call

```
char_sprite(display_surface,place_holder, (text_x -100, text_y - 25))
```

before

```
display_text_animation(display_surface, 
                       BLACK, 
                       "hello world", 
                       (text_x + 65, text_y + 25))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I have tried that before. The issue is that when I try to call it before the display text function it just doesn't show up at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MadelineMathews just to be sure, when you did it that way, you did update right? cuz if you dont update ofc the blit wont show.

Comment: I think so, idk. I'm using a website called repl.it so it works a bit differently but I'm pretty sure it updates automatically.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out! Thank you for your help though!